Kafka connect transforms not working with neo4j sink connector
I have configured neo4j sink connector as described in their doc here and it works. Now i am trying to add some transformations to it so i can change some values of the payload. But this does not seem to have any effect on the message recieved by the connector.
Connector config:
"transforms" : "InsertField",
"transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.InsertField.static.field": "MessageSource",
"transforms.InsertField.static.value": "dummy"

I have set env ENV CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL="TRACE" so that it will print the message in logs.
